# Spivak: what precisely is "bounds on the error" in Taylor theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The following problem is from Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 5. (a) In Problem 11-41 you showed that the equation $x^2=\cos{x}$ has precisely two solutions. Use the third degree Taylor polynomial of
>    $\cos$ to show that the solutions are approximately $\pm \sqrt{2/3}$,
>    and find bounds on the error. Then use the fifth degree Taylor
>    polynomial to get a better approximation.

What precisely does "bounds on the error" mean here?

Consider first the third degree Taylor polynomial and the use of Taylor's theorem

$$\cos{x}=P_{3,0}(x)+R_{3,0}(x)\tag{1}$$

where $P_{3,0}$ is the third degree Taylor Polynomial at $0$. Then

$$P_{3,0}(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$R_{3,0}(x)=\frac{\cos{t}}{4!}x^4, t\in (0,x)$$

$$\implies |R_{3,0}(x)|\leq \frac{x^4}{4!}$$

If we equate the polynomial $P_{3,0}(x)$ to $x^2$ we obtain $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

At these particular values of $x$, we know that the remainder is less than $\frac{1}{54}$. What this means is that the value of $\cos{\left (\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right )}$ is within $\frac{1}{54}$ of $\frac{2}{3}$.

However, this does not tell us much about how far off we are from the actual $x$ at which $\cos{(x)}=x^2$.

Note that the problem statement makes reference to a previous problem 11-41. In that problem we showed that the two solutions to $x^2=\cos{x}$ are such that $|x|<1$. Thus $R_{3,0}(x)<\frac{1}{4!}$.

If we equate $(1)$ to $x^2$, however, and use $R(x)$ to denote $R_{3,0}(x)$ we obtain

$$1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R(x)=x^2$$

$$|3x^2-2|\leq 2|R(x)|\leq 2\frac{x^4}{4!}\leq \frac{1}{12}$$

$$\implies \frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\leq |x|\leq \frac{5}{6}$$

So, based on bounds on the remainder, we were able to determine bounds on $x$.

My questions are

1. what is the "bounds on the error" in this case with a third degree Taylor polynomial?
2. in general, how do we know that the value of $x$ we found by equating the Taylor polynomial to $x^2$ is within the intervals we found wherein $f(x)=x^2$? In the case above, it happened to be true, ie $\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\leq |x|=\left |\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right | \leq \frac{5}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

1. I would say that in this case the bound on the error is
   $
   |R(x)|\leq \frac{1}{24},
   $
   which is what you get when you equate (1) to $x^2$.
2. I am not sure I understand your second question, could you maybe reformulate it?

Comment: If we equate the polynomial $P_{3,0}(x)$ to $x^2$ we obtain $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. This is just the value of $x$ at which the Taylor polynomial equals $x^2$, but we want the $x$ at which $\cos{x}$ is equal to $x^2$. We found a range for such $x$, namely $\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\leq |x|\leq \frac{5}{6}$. Is it always the case that the first values we found, namely $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ are always within this range we found? Ie, in a more general case, do we get a result like  $\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\leq |x|=\left |\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right | \leq \frac{5}{6}$?

Comment: I mean, if you just equate the Taylor polynomial without the error term with the other desired function (which I am assuming has no error terms, like in the case of $x^2$) of course your range is given by the error term $R(x)$.

I mean, you could consider two functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$, their respective Taylor polynomials $P_f$, $P_g$, and the error terms $R_f$, $R_g$, and work out how the range is given in the general case. It should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that Spivak's solution manual arguments to these problems were lacking some details (and were phrased a little weirdly). I wrote this explanation for myself...hopefully it helps anyone else working on this problem

---

The solution manual starts off by writing the following (correct) $3$rd-degree Taylor Polynomial expansion of $\cos$: $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R_{3,0}(x)$

An important consideration for the above equation is that what is REALLY being said is:

> $\forall x \in \mathbb R: 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R_{3,0}(x)=\cos(x) \quad (*_1)$

Now, suppose that the following is true (by problem 11-41, we know that such a statement is, in fact, true):

> $\exists x \in \mathbb R: \cos(x)=x^2 \quad (*_2)$.

Further, as explained in the solution manual to problem 11-41, we know that all such $x$ satisfying this statement must also satisfy: $x \in [-1,1]$.

Therefore, the above sentence combined with $(*_1)$ and $(*_2)$ gives us:

> $\exists x \in [-1,1]: 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R_{3,0}(x)=x^2$

which is equivalently  written as:

> $\exists x \in [-1,1]:\frac{3x^2}{2}-1=R_{3,0}(x) \iff \exists x \in [-1,1]:3x^2-2=2R_{3,0}(x) \quad (*_3)$

The change in domain is important here, as it allows us to set a finite bound on what $R_{3,0}(x)$ can evaluate to. Specifically, by work carried out in Chapter 20's exposition, we know that the $3$rd-degree remainder to $\cos$ is: $R_{3,0}(x)=\frac{\cos(x)^{(4)}}{4!}x^4$. Working out the derivative, we know that $R_{3,0}(x)=\frac{\cos(x)^{(4)}}{4!}x^4=\frac{\cos(x)}{4!}x^4$, which ensures us that $R_{3,0}(x) \in \left[-\frac{x^4}{4!},\frac{x^4}{4!}\right]$. Because $x^4$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$, given that $x \in [-1,1]$, we must have that: $R_{3,0}(x) \in \left[-\frac{1^4}{4!},\frac{1^4}{4!}\right]=\left[-\frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{24}\right]$.

Of course, then, we have that:

> $2R_{3,0}(x) \in \left[-\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12}\right] \quad (*_4)$

Combining $(*_3)$ and $(*_4)$ gives us:

> $\exists x \in [-1,1]:3x^2-2 \in \left[-\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12}\right] \quad (*_5)$

Suppose that $z$ satisfies the above statement, we have, then, that:

$$-\frac{1}{12}\leq 3z^2-2 \leq \frac{1}{12} \quad (\dagger)$$

Algebraic manipulations can then proceed as follows:

\begin{align}&-\frac{1}{12}\leq 3z^2-2 \leq \frac{1}{12} \implies \\& \frac{23}{12}\leq 3z^2\leq \frac{25}{12} \implies \\&\frac{23}{36} \leq z^2 \leq \frac{25}{36} \implies \\&\sqrt{\frac{23}{36}} \leq |z| \leq \sqrt{\frac{25}{36}}\implies \\&\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6} \leq |z| \leq \frac{5}{6}\end{align}

From absolute value rules, we know that this final statement is equivalent to:

$$z \in \left[-\frac{5}{6},-\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\right] \cup \left[\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6},\frac{5}{6}\right]$$

Finally, we can emphasize the point that Spivak intended (albeit awkwardly / confusingly) to state: the solution to $3x^2-2=0$ is $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}=\pm 2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$

Is $-2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} \in \left[-\frac{5}{6},-\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\right]$ and is $2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} \in \left[\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6},\frac{5}{6}\right]$?

Quickly, it is easy to check that $2\sqrt 6 \lt 5$ and $2\sqrt 6 \gt \sqrt {23}$. Accordingly, indeed:

> $-2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} \in \left[-\frac{5}{6},-\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6}\right]$ and $2\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} \in \left[\frac{\sqrt{23}}{6},\frac{5}{6}\right]$